# Is there any way to stop Java from automatically creating new lines in the console output?

Tags: java

I started learning Java a month back, and I have been using Eclipse as the workspace. Although I love the layout of it, I've been having trouble with what the console outputs. Specifically, the console will automatically create new lines in the output, despite no call for the creation of a new line being in the code.

For example, something like this:

```
     public class myClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int [] array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        for(int x : array)
        {
            System.out.println(x + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Will print the following:

> 10,
>
> 20,
>
> 30,
>
> 40,
>
> 50,

Is there any way to stop this from happening? I don't want future projects to have such odd spacing in between the lines.

Comment: What do you think `ln` in `println` represents? What happens when you remove it?

Comment: use `print` other than `println`

Comment: Guess what, the "ln" in "println" means "line", and it always appends a line break. Use "print" instead.

Comment: You could use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` too.

Comment: `System.out.println(IntStream.of(array).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah, or that ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's NOT Eclipse. It is the Java method `System.out.println` you invoked:

```
public void println(String s)
```

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

```
public void print(String s)
```

> Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

Use `print()` istead if you want to print all numbers in one line.

A much shorter way to do is:

```
String output = String.join(",", array);  // Java8
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to stop creating new lines

Remove `ln` in your `println`

`ln` represents new line if ignore it there no comes new line.

```
public class myClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int [] array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        for(int x : array)
        {
            System.out.print(x + ", "); // println changed to print
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

10, 20, 30, 40, 50